# ionic - Reduce image quality (having a base64 string)

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to reduce an image quality. When I use the camera, I have the CameraOptions with the quality property, where I can set any value from 0 to 100.

In my problem, I have an image downloaded from internet into a base64 string. I want to reduce this image quality, as camera does very well. But using the ImageResizer I have the following options:

```
    let options = {
            uri: uri,
            folderName: 'Protonet',
            quality: 90,
            width: 1280,
            height: 1280
    } as ImageResizerOptions;
```

It receives an uri as a property, but I have a base64 string.

So here is the thing:

1. How to convert this base64 string into an uri (but I don't think this is a solution, generating I/O is bad)
2. How to reduce the quality without having to convert that base64 to uri?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `CameraOptions with the quality property,` ?? Never seen such.

Comment: Why did you put that downloaded image in a base64 string? And didnt that image have an url which you can parse to an uri?

Comment: CameraOptions has quality 'greenapps' - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

Comment: Sorry i should have seen that this is Ionic. Forget my remark please.

Comment: Why I put that in a base64 string? Because I will work with that value in my page and I will save in database as that. So you suggest that I should not work with base64?

Comment: How would you work with that in your page? In which page? Converting to base64 increases the amount of bytes with 30% so i consider this bad practise.

Comment: Do you know another way to have an image in memory in ionic besides base64? Remember, ionic in the end is javascript.

Comment: I do not know Ionic. No idea.